# Can I search/replace in multiple .txt files from terminal with specific conditions

Tags: macos, replace, terminal, conditional-statements

I have 2500 `.txt` files in which I would like to `replace` all occurrences of `-do-` by `+do+` only when they occur between the following opening and closing tags:

`<X> </X>, <O> </O>, <&> </&>, <del> </del>, <+> </+>, <*> </*>`

I have found how to find/replace with sed with this code:

```
sed -i '' 's/-do-/+do+/g' *.txt
```

But I was wondering if there was any way to add such a condition to this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You will need two things:

1) improve your search pattern to look for the tags, like this: `/<[X0&]>-do-<\/[X0&]>/`

2) enclose your tags in groups and replicate them in target with backreferences like this: `s/\(foo\)bar/\1baz/g` (this will give you `foobar -> foobaz`).

This will get you started: `sed -i 's/\(<[X]>\)-do-\(<\/[X]>\)/\1+do+\2/g' *.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I might be wrong (I'm not fully sure on how to read the code, and I get the following error message when running it: 
`sed: 1: "S1A-001.txt": invalid command code S`), but I think I was somewhat. There is actually a whole bunch of text between the tags `<X>` and `</X>`, and within this text, I would like to replace all occurrences of -do- by +do+. Any way this could be adapted? Thanks a lot.

Comment: A quick patch for that would be `sed -i 's/\(<[X]>.*\)-do-\(.*<\/[X]>\)/\1+do+\2/g' *.txt`. You should familiarize yourself with regular expressions, that's what all this mumbo jumbo is called :-)

Comment: Will do :-) I'm still having some problem, though: This should replace a few thousands occurrences, but only replaces 2, and only really short matches. I figure that it may be because of line breaks not being matched… So I tried this (and a bunch of other possibilities): `sed -i '' 's/\(<[X]>[\n|.]*\)-do-\([\n|.]*<\/[X]>\)/\1+do+\2/g' *.txt` but it still doesn't work :(